# Expected comma json(514) in VSCode settings.json

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, settings

An error appeared while I was inputting custom tags for Better Comments in settings.json. The problem?

```
    "better-comments.tags": [
        {
          "tag": "!",
          "color": "#FF2D00",
          "strikethrough": false,
          "underline": false,
          "backgroundColor": "transparent",
          "bold": false,
          "italic": false
        },
        {
          "tag": "?",
          "color": "#3498DB",
          "strikethrough": false,
          "underline": false,
          "backgroundColor": "transparent",
          "bold": false,
          "italic": false
        },
        {
          "tag": "//",
          "color": "#474747",
          "strikethrough": true,
          "underline": false,
          "backgroundColor": "transparent",
          "bold": false,
          "italic": false
        },
        {
          "tag": "todo",
          "color": "#FF8C00",
          "strikethrough": false,
          "underline": false,
          "backgroundColor": "transparent",
          "bold": false,
          "italic": false
        },
        {
          "tag": "*",
          "color": "#98C379",
          "strikethrough": false,
          "underline": false,
          "backgroundColor": "transparent",
          "bold": false,
          "italic": false
        }
    ]
```

In the middle of the *better-comments.tags* tag, an error showed up which said,
`Expected comma jsonc(514)`.

I decided to split *comm* and *ents* and wrote it as `"better-comm,ents.tags": [`. Strangely enough, the code dimmed after the change.

Did I discover my solution, and if not, is there any you can provide to me?

(And, oh, forgot to add, there weren't any original tags anywhere. I used the search feature and it turned back with no results.)

Comment: And if you mark the spot of the error it is useful fir us to determine the problem

Comment: It is because you did not put a comma after the **preceding** setting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma after `"editor.linkedEditing": true`
so it should be like this: `"editor.linkedEditing": true,`